# PhoneGap 2.9.1 - Camera; crashing due to background process limit

Tags: android, cordova, camera

so after a lot of investigation, I finally made my app able to resume state (I simply just modified the OnCreate method  in the MainAcitivity.java to load a "restore" page on activity kill if there is a saved bundle instance)

I believe once I fix this final problem, all will be good and I can finally sleep.

HOW do I get the Activity/Intent result from a Camera in PhoneGap once the app has been killed off due to the Background Processes limit or the possibility of "Do not keep activities being checked" (I have a surprising amount of users who have these restrictions enabled)

I thought it might be possible to make the camera save the file in a temp directory and then I just pass the URI through javascript as a hash url (so it'd be something like file:///android_www/index-restore.html#URI_TO_IMAGE)

But my only issue is - How do I even begin this in PhoneGap? I know what to do for everthing bar the temp storage of the image and retrieving the location through onCreate

Comment: All I need to do is figure out how to get SharedPreferences working between the projects and then it will be good :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally managed it, wrote a hacky solution but it works.

1. I modified the CordovaInterface and CordovaActivity by adding a function called "getSharedPref" which returns a shared preference that can be accessed throughout the app.
2. I modified Camera Launcher to force the stored name to be temp.jpg or temp.png depending on what ever input, then store it within the preference.
3. On the MainActivity.java, I use this.getSharedPref() if a bundle instance is not null, and then check for the key. Unfortunately the only way I could assign the variable in Cordova was by doing

   ```
   super.loadUrl("javascript: var global_image = '" + file + "'");
   ```

then I did the usual routines to add the file in my program and it all work so far! Happy days

Down the track I will probably write a plugin to use, using super.loadUrl("file:///blablabla#" + file); didn't seem to work.

The only issues so far are that Images aren't resized and rotated correctly, and I still need to implement this for the PhotoGallery but so far so good.

edit:
I've managed to get the photos resized and re-orientated :) Next issue is implementing it onto the Photo Gallery now - intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file); doesn't seem to apply for some reason.

edit:

Latest update - so it turns out AFTER the App has seemingly "crashed", you still get the Intent back regardless, so modifying the source code even more it now auto-calls a global javascript function called "customRestore", which passes over information gathered from the intent and then goes through the normal routine of adding a photo.